# So is Ivan dead?

Tags: oglaf

In *[Oglaf](https://oglaf.com)* (**warning:** not always SFW), we see the apprentice, Ivan, getting shot with the Arrow of Regret. In the next story, ["Lament"](https://oglaf.com/lament/) *(SFW)*, Sandoval, the Ambassador of Xoan, is informed that Ivan is not dead, but in a state of Deep Magical Sleep.

So is this true? What is the current state of Ivan? Is he indeed alive and in deep sleep, or is he dead and was Sandoval lied to?

Comment: Upvote just for asking an Oglaf question.

Comment: "not always" suggests that it sometimes is SFW

Comment: @OrangeDog some individual comics are, such as "The Fountain of Doubt".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Oglaf twitter feed](https://twitter.com/Oglaf):

> "He's not well, but he definitely isn't dead - so he'll absolutely be back (once he wakes up)." --[Jun 21st 2011](https://twitter.com/oglaf/status/83063067654619136)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Ivan and the Mistress are both definitively alive.

> [@Oglaf - Bodil Bodilson](https://twitter.com/Oglaf/status/594395859749470208)
>
> *Yes, they [Ivan and Mistress] are coming back. We're still writing,
>   but it's a long-arse fukken EPIC of a story so it's still got some
>   work to do on it...*